# Simple web server in Flash

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I just got into Node.JS and am loving it but I am wondering if I am learning it the right way or using it. This is basically a simple server in Flash but I want to see if am doing it right with handling client connections. This makes a new `CurrentPlayer` after it gets a login packet and sets the ID and username once they connect.

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((c) => {

    c.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });

    c.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + c.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        CheckPacket(data.toString(), c);
    });

    c.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + c.remoteAddress +' '+ c.remotePort);
    });
});

server.on('connection', function (c) {
    console.log('client connected > ' + c.remoteAddress);
});

server.on('error', (err) => {
    throw err;
});
server.listen(888, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on 888');
});


function CheckPacket(packet, client) {
    if (packet.startsWith("<")) {
        client.write("<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='888'/></cross-domain-policy>\0");
    } else {
        var re = /\0/g;
        packet = packet.toString().replace(re, "");
        var json = JSON.parse(packet);
        JsonPacket(json, client);
    }
}

function JsonPacket(json, client) {
    switch (json.type) {
        case 'login':

            client.name = new CurrentPlayer();
            client.name.id = json.id;

            console.log(client.name);

            break;

        default:
            console.log('Unknown json: ' + json);
            break;
    }
}


function CurrentPlayer() {
    this.id = 0;
}
```